# some colores are not showing or missing in my laravel project and i dont know how to fix it

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, visual-studio-code

[image: that's what it looks like on visual studio code]

[image: this is the second screenshot]

some colores are not showing or missing in my laravel project and i dont know how to fix it
i tried to change the color theme but it didn't work .
i also tried the laravel extention ... but the syntaxe highlight doesnt work properly

here is the code and the screenshot of how it appears is above

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class usercontroller extends Controller
{
    function login(Request $req)
        {
            return $req->input();
        }
    public function index ()
        {
            return view('student');
        }
    public function creer()
        {
            return view('create');
        }
    public function update($id)
        {
            return view('update',[

            ]);
        }
    public function delete()
        {
            return view('delete');
        }

}
```

```
Route::get('/',[usercontroller::class,'index'] );

Route::get('/create',[usercontroller::class,'creer'] );

Route::get('/update/{id}', [usercontroller::class,'update'] );

Route::get('/delete', [usercontroller::class,'delete'] );

Route::get('/login',function(){
    return view ('login');
});
```

Comment: you have syntax highlighting, so if you you don't like this choose a different one or write one (TextMate grammer) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to have coloured syntax you should ensure that PHP is picked at the language picker in your VSCode (see screenshot below)

[image]